# How to correctly get the errors at the end of the Oracle function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This is the code that I have at the end of my procedure. It's supposed to show the errors if something went wrong:

```
IF return_status = 'E' OR return_status = 'U'
  THEN
     MESSAGE := MESSAGE || 'return status: ' || return_status || ' msg: ';
     IF (FND_MSG_PUB.Count_Msg > 0)
     THEN
        FOR i IN 1 .. FND_MSG_PUB.Count_Msg
        LOOP
           FND_MSG_PUB.Get (p_msg_index       => i,
                            p_encoded         => 'F',
                            p_data            => out_message,
                            p_msg_index_OUT   => l_msg_index_OUT);
           MESSAGE := MESSAGE || ' ' || out_message;
        END LOOP;
     END IF;
  END IF;

  RETURN (MESSAGE);
```

MESSAGE is VARCHAR2(4000) variable;

I execute the procedure multiple times and quite quickly I get the following error: `[Error] ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`

This is the output (the number is lead_id, the rest is concatenated error message):

```
192774 
192930 
192966 
193714 
193714 
193714 
193848 
193848 
193848 
193848 
194096 
194096 
194109 
194109 
194593 
194593 
194124 
195055 
194875 
195451 
195451 
195451 
195451 
195451 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
191239 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
191239 
187351 
192237 
195868 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
195939 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
196827 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
196977 
196977 
196977 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 493.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
197024 
197060 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 493.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
197158 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 493.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
197280 
197280 
197420 
197420 
197420 
197502 
197502 
197502 
197502 return status: E msg:  Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 616.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 493.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 11682.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. Cannot read value for profile option USER_ID. The column(s), PRODUCT_CATEGORY, has an invalid value(s), 583.  Please ensure that the entered identifier or combination of identifiers exist in the database.
197502 
197761 
189846 
189846 
198500 
198500 
198500 
174335 
174335 
174335 
207133
```

You can easily see that the message contains the errors from the previous call. How can I rewrite it, so it only contains the correct message? I thought about getting the last message only instead all < FND_MSG_PUB.Count_Msg, but I am not sure if that's correct. I am a .NET developer and this is our legacy code. I also found this on the Internet: http://orclpps.blogspot.com/2007/06/fndmsgpub-for-error-logging-in-oracle.html which also makes use of all the messages. Is it possible to clear the FND_MSG_PUB somehow or find only the errors resulting from the current call?

Comment: Just set the message string to null first.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look into the following procedures available in `FND_MSG_PUB`:

```
--  Procedure   Initialize
--
--  Usage       Used by API callers and developers to intialize the
--              global message table.
--  Desc        Clears the G_msg_tbl and resets all its global
--              variables. Except for the message level threshold.
--

PROCEDURE Initialize;

--  PROCEDURE   Delete_Msg
--
--  Usage       Used to delete a specific message from the message
--              list, or clear the whole message list.
--
--  Desc        If instructed to delete a specific message, the
--              message is removed from the message table and the
--              table is compressed by moving the messages coming
--              after the deleted messages up one entry in the message
--              table.
--              If there is no entry found the Delete procedure does
--              nothing, and  no exception is raised.
--              If delete is passed no parameters it deletes the whole
--              message table.
--
--  Prameters   p_msg_index     IN NUMBER := NULL Optional
--                  holds the index of the message to be deleted.
--

PROCEDURE Delete_Msg
(   p_msg_index IN    NUMBER    :=      NULL
);
```

Call `Delete_Msg` to clear the messages after you have processed them or alternatively just before a call to Oracle API. I can't say if you'll find use for `Initialize` or not as this depends on other factors of you application you're not showing to us. Example (not guaranteed to compile):

```
IF return_status = 'E' OR return_status = 'U'
THEN
  IF FND_MSG_PUB.Count_Msg > 0
  THEN
    FOR i IN 1 .. FND_MSG_PUB.Count_Msg
    LOOP
      FND_MSG_PUB.Get (p_msg_index       => i,
                       p_encoded         => 'F',
                       p_data            => out_message,
                       p_msg_index_OUT   => l_msg_index_OUT);
      MESSAGE := MESSAGE || ' ' || out_message;
    END LOOP;

    FND_MSG_PUB.Delete_Msg;
  END IF;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

`MESSAGE` is appended with existing text can't it be like this, by overwriting/nullifying ?

```
IF return_status = 'E' OR return_status = 'U'
  THEN

     /*MESSAGE := MESSAGE || 'return status: ' || return_status || ' msg: ';*/


    -- Message is appended with existing text can't it be like this, by overwriting/nullifying ?

     MESSAGE  := 'return status: ' || return_status || ' msg: ';
     IF (FND_MSG_PUB.Count_Msg > 0)
     THEN
        FOR i IN 1 .. FND_MSG_PUB.Count_Msg
        LOOP
           FND_MSG_PUB.Get (p_msg_index       => i,
                            p_encoded         => 'F',
                            p_data            => out_message,
                            p_msg_index_OUT   => l_msg_index_OUT);
           MESSAGE := MESSAGE || ' ' || out_message;
        END LOOP;
     END IF;
  END IF;

  RETURN (MESSAGE);
```

Also, In `PL/SQL` Varchar2 supports **32K**.

Comment: I tried that before, but it didn't change anything. The "bad" thing happens in the LOOP...

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with how you are using `FND_MSG_PUB` to hold the messages.  My guess is that its package state is not being reset each time you call the procedure; so each time you run the procedure, you get all the messages that have built up over time, which would keep increasing.

Perhaps you could reset `FND_MSG_PUB`'s state on each call to the procedure; perhaps you could look only at the message with the highest number.  Whether either of these is correct and reliable depends on how the package is used throughout your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see an example with Item Category assignment to Items.

Here, you can see the parameter `"p_init_msg_list"` is set to `false`, which means the message API won't be initialised and concatenate all the errors stored.

```
inv_item_category_pub.create_category_assignment (
    p_api_version         => 1.0
    , p_init_msg_list       => fnd_api.g_false
    , p_commit              => fnd_api.g_false
    , x_return_status       => l_return_status
    , x_errorcode           => l_errorcode
    , x_msg_count           => l_msg_count
    , x_msg_data            => l_msg_data
    , p_category_id         => l_category_id
    , p_category_set_id     => l_category_set_id
    , p_inventory_item_id   => l_inventory_item_id
    , p_organization_id     => l_organization_id
);
            FOR k IN 1..fnd_msg_pub.count_msg LOOP
                fnd_msg_pub.get (
                    p_msg_index       => k
                    , p_encoded         => 'F'
                    , p_data            => l_msg_data
                    , p_msg_index_out   => l_msg_index_out
                );
                dbms_output.put_line ('l_msg_data:= ' || l_msg_data);
                IF l_msg_data IS NOT NULL THEN
                    l_error_message := l_error_message
                                       || '-'
                                       || l_msg_data;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
```

If you want to check the error respective to the transaction, set the parameter `"p_init_msg_list"` to `true` or manually initialise the message in the loop.

```
FND_MSG_PUB.initialize;
```